# Can't export events to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-events

We're trying to export events from our web site to Facebook throught Graph API, and it worked fine, but now this functionality is impossible to do.

I did some research about this, and found that many pages (including Facebook API Documentation) mention that something is out of date,
meaning nowadays developers can't upload events anymore, only read events from Facebook.

Is there another tool that does this?

Comment: No there is no API for creating events.

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish